# Receiving incoming traffic without external IP and port forwarding

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a virtual machine in the datacenter with an external IP. I can connect via SSH to this virtual machine from my desktop, but this virtual machine has no way of accessing any ports on my desktop.

Is there any I can make virtual-machine-ip:1234 forward traffic to desktop:1234? I was thinking of doing this via some sort of SSH tunnel, but normally SSH tunnels work the other way around.

My end goal is sending growl notifications to my desktop on port 23053, but there is no way to set up port forwarding, so I can only receive growl notifications from within the network, not from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

Ssh tunnels can be set both ways. Just stablish with `remote` or `-R`:

```
ssh -R 1234:localhost:1234 virtual-machine-ip
```

Note: tcp forwarding must be enabled on your remote server, under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```